# Variable readonly

Tags: c, variables, readonly

How to make a variable readonly in C?

```
const int a = 10; //Is it readonly variable?
```

If not, How readonly variable looks like in C? Please give an example.

Comment: is it so hard to test it with `a = 11;`?

Comment: As long as you don't mess with pointers on `a`, yes, it is "readonly".

Comment: @yi_H: No its not hard dude. That i know too. But should i call variable declared with const as a readonly or not was one of my doubt. :)

Comment: just call it const or constant. never heard the term "readonly" in C context in my life.

Comment: @Cicada: Other than this. Is there any other way to make the variable readonly in C?

Comment: @yi_H: I have heard, thats why i asked. :)

Comment: You can use `#define a 10` but that wouldn't make `a` a variable. Just a guaranteed value, `10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is readonly. But if you will use pointers' magic not accurately you can at random edit it

Comment: Technically this is invoking UB, which might or might not "edit" it, since with UB anything could happen.

Comment: @RiaD: I am sorry but may i know what is UB?

Comment: @Abhineet: undefined behavior

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, `const` allow a single initialisation at the definition.